# Filter: blur is causing transparent background

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, blur

I am making an off-canvas nav for my site on mobile view. When I click the hamburger menu the below is expected to happen:

- off canvas nav slides in from the side (translateX(100vw) -> (0vw))
- Everything other then the nav and header logo will be blurred **(having trouble here)**
- Hamburger menu changes in to an X

However when I click the hamburger icon the nav slides in but for some reason the background is transparent and I can't figure out what is causing this behavior.

I don't know which part of my code is causing the problem so I don't know which part to post. I got a setup and as you can see the bg for the nav is transparent after it slides out....

https://codepen.io/tomokiota/pen/jOxRNza

[image]

```
body.blur main > * {
filter: blur(5px) brightness(0.7);
pointer-events: none;
user-select: none;
z-index: -1;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
z-index:-1
```

on the main tag wasn't being applied because my offcanvas nav had a position of fixed but my main didn't have any specified position value.
After setting position of relative to main, problem was solved.